# Order in which library directories are searched and linked

Tags: gcc, linker, centos, ld

I am having difficulty understanding the order in which directories are searched for linking to libraries.  I have a CentOS6 system and 3 versions of gcc, 4.4.7, 4.7.2, 4.9.2.  The system version is 4.4.7 and version 4.7.2 and 4.9.2 are modules.  In `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/` there two files, `gcc-4.7.2.conf` and `gcc-4.9.2.conf` which contain the paths to the 4.7.2 and 4.9.2 libraries.

I created a simple C++ program, `main.cpp`

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


int main(void)
{
    cout << "Hello You!" << endl;
    printf("Back at you!\n");

    return 0;
}
```

compiling it with g++-4.4.7 and running `ldd a.out`, I see

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff5535b000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /nonstandardpath/gcc-4.7.2/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00002ac12de73000)
libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00002ac12e17a000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /nonstandardpath/gcc-4.7.2/lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00002ac12e3ff000)
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00002ac12e614000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00002ac12dc51000)
```

Looking at `man ld`, it states (under `-rpath-link=dir`) :

> The linker uses the following search paths to locate required shared
>   libraries:
>
> 1. Any directories specified by -rpath-link options.
> 2. Any directories specified by -rpath options.  The difference between -rpath and
>                 -rpath-link is that directories specified by -rpath options are included in the
>                 executable and used at runtime, whereas the -rpath-link option is only effective at
>                 link time. Searching -rpath in this way is only supported by native linkers and
>                 cross linkers which have been configured with the --with-sysroot option.
> 3. On an ELF system, for native linkers, if the -rpath and -rpath-link options were not
>                 used, search the contents of the environment variable "LD_RUN_PATH".
> 4. On SunOS, if the -rpath option was not used, search any directories specified using
>                 -L options.
> 5. For a native linker, the search the contents of the environment variable
>                 "LD_LIBRARY_PATH".
> 6. For a native ELF linker, the directories in "DT_RUNPATH" or "DT_RPATH" of a shared
>                 library are searched for shared libraries needed by it. The "DT_RPATH" entries are
>                 ignored if "DT_RUNPATH" entries exist.
> 7. The default directories, normally /lib and /usr/lib.
> 8. For a native linker on an ELF system, if the file /etc/ld.so.conf exists, the list
>                 of directories found in that file.
>
>    If the required shared library is not found, the linker will issue a warning and
>             continue with the link.

It does not state the order in which the directories are searched.  From my example above, it appears that `/etc/ld.so.conf.d` is searched before `/usr/lib` or `/lib`

QUESTION : what is the order in which linker searches for libraries (e.g. LD_LIBRARY_PATH, ld.so.conf.d, -rpath, -L)?

Answer (score 1):

[The online man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html) states the order for `ld`:

> When resolving shared object dependencies, the dynamic linker first
>          inspects each dependency string to see if it contains a slash (this
>          can occur if a shared object pathname containing slashes was
>          specified at link time).
>
> If a slash is found, then the dependency
>          string is interpreted as a (relative or absolute) pathname, and the
>          shared object is loaded using that pathname.
>
> If a shared object dependency does not contain a slash, then it is searched for in the following order:
>
> - Using the directories specified in the DT_RPATH dynamic section attribute of the binary if present and DT_RUNPATH attribute does not exist.  Use of DT_RPATH is deprecated.
> - Using the environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH (unless the executable is being run in secure-execution mode; see below).  in which case it is ignored.
> - Using the directories specified in the DT_RUNPATH dynamic section attribute of the binary if present.  Such directories are searched only to find those objects required by DT_NEEDED (direct dependencies) entries and do not apply to those objects' children, which must themselves have their own DT_RUNPATH entries.  This is unlike DT_RPATH, which is applied to searches for all children in the dependency tree.
> - From the cache file /etc/ld.so.cache, which contains a compiled list of candidate shared objects previously found in the augmented library path.  If, however, the binary was linked with the -z nodeflib linker option, shared objects in the default paths are skipped.  Shared objects installed in hardware capability directories (see below) are preferred to other shared objects.
> - In the default path /lib, and then /usr/lib.  (On some 64-bit architectures, the default paths for 64-bit shared objects are /lib64, and then /usr/lib64.)  If the binary was linked with the -z nodeflib linker option, this step is skipped.

Taken from the 2017-09-15 version. I assume older versions of ld are similar.