# Why is --rpath being superseded when building shared library?

Tags: gcc, ld

I am working on a CentOS machine.  I have a file (`test.c`) that I'm compiling into a shared library.

`test.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <quadmath.h>
int my_func(void){
    __float128 r;
    r = strtoflt128 ("1.2345678", NULL);
    int * b = malloc(sizeof(int) * 5);
    double a = 10*M_PI_2q;
    printf("Hello world  %f\n",a);
    return 0;
}
```

To compile it :

```
$ gcc -c -fPIC test.c -o test.o
$ gcc -shared -Wl,--verbose -Wl,-soname,poo.so -Wl,-rpath,/opt/gcc/5.5.0/lib/ -o poo.so test.o -lquadmath
$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH   ### This shouldn't matter?
    /opt/gcc/5.5.0/lib
```

From the verbose output from `ld`, it looks like it `/opt/gcc/5.5.0/lib64/libquadmath.so.0` is found (which is what I want). I.e.

```
.
.
.
attempt to open /opt/gcc/5.5.0/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/5.5.0/libquadmath.so failed
attempt to open /opt/gcc/5.5.0/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/5.5.0/libquadmath.a failed
attempt to open /opt/gcc/5.5.0/bin/../lib/gcc/libquadmath.so failed
attempt to open /opt/gcc/5.5.0/bin/../lib/gcc/libquadmath.a failed
attempt to open /opt/gcc/5.5.0/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/5.5.0/../../../../lib64/libquadmath.so succeeded 
-lquadmath (/opt/gcc/5.5.0/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/5.5.0/../../../../lib64/libquadmath.so)
 .
 .
 .
```

However, when I look with `ldd poo.so`, it *does not* have the correct library. I.e.

```
$ ldd poo.so 
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffc0e8e000)
    libquadmath.so.0 => /act/gcc-4.7.2/lib64/libquadmath.so.0 (0x00002aea8fd39000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00002aea8ff6f000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00002aea90303000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00002aea8f8f2000)
```

I am using `gcc` version 5.5.0 and would like `poo.so` to link to `/opt/gcc/5.5.0/lib/libquadmath.so.0` instead of the 4.7.2 version.

I think this is related to the existence of files in `/etc/ld.so.conf` specifying the location of the older libraries. I.e.

```
$ cat /etc/ld.so.conf.d/gcc-4.7.2.conf 
/act/gcc-4.7.2/lib64
/act/gcc-4.7.2/lib
```

The man page of `ld` (as I inquired [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36015224/order-in-which-library-directories-are-searched-and-linked)) is less than useful.

**QUESTION** : I specify `-rpath` when linking and building the shared library, yet I don't understand why it is finding the older gcc-4.7.2 version of the quadmath library. Why does the linker seem to prioritize the paths in `/etc/ld.so.conf` and ignore the `-rpath` option?  How can I specify the library location at compile time and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand the solution, first we must understand the incorrect thinking.

1. I did not realize that there **two** utilities doing linking.  There is `ld` (which is used at compile time) and `ld.so` (which is used at run time).  The man page of `ld.so` describes how libraries are found at run time. To summarize it searches :

   a) Directories specified in `DT_RPATH`

   b) Directories specified in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

   c) Directories in DT_RUNPATH dynamic section of binary (if present)

   d) Cache file `/etc/ld.so.cache`

   e) The default path /lib and then /usr/lib
2. The man page of `ld` primarily confused me.  It says under the -rpath option:

   > Add a directory to the runtime library search path.  This is used when linking an ELF executable with shared objects

   I thought that passing `-rpath` when building a shared library would
   guarantee that it would find the library without needing to set
   `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.  **Wrong**. This feature only seems to be useful
   when **building an executable**, not a shared library.  There is an `-rpath-link` option, but I couldn't figure out how to make it work.

You can see this by doing the following:

```
$ cat test2.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <quadmath.h>
int main(void){
    __float128 r;
    r = strtoflt128 ("1.2345678", NULL);
    int * b = malloc(sizeof(int) * 5); 
    double a = 10*M_PI_2q;
    printf("Hello world  %f\n",a);
    return 0;
}
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=
$ which gcc 
/opt/gcc/5.5.0/bin/gcc
$ gcc -Wl,-rpath,/opt/gcc/5.5.0/lib64 test2.c -lquadmath
$ ldd a.out 
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffff34f000)
libquadmath.so.0 => /opt/gcc/5.5.0/lib64/libquadmath.so.0 (0x00002b9c35e07000)
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00002b9c36069000)
libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00002b9c363fd000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00002b9c35be5000)
$ readelf -a a.out  | grep -i rpath
0x000000000000000f (RPATH)              Library rpath: [/opt/gcc/5.5.0/lib64]
```

3. The way that the linker found the correct library was by utilizing the path to `/opt/gcc/5.5.0/bin/gcc` and looking at relative paths with respect to it.  I checked this by setting `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=` and excluding the `rpath` argument, i.e. `gcc -shared -Wl,--verbose -Wl,-soname,poo.so -o poo.so test.o -lquadmath`.  Even then, it was able to link to the correct `libquadmath.so.0` library.
4. The reason that `ldd poo.so` could not find the correct library was because it wanted the **64-bit** version of the `libquadmath.so.0` library IS NOT **`/opt/gcc/5.5.0/lib/libquadmath.so.0`**.  That is the **32-bit** version of the library.  This is obvious once you inspect both versions of the library and see that the they are ELF64 and ELF32 respectively (e.g. `readelf -a /opt/gcc/5.5.0/lib64/libquadmath.so.0 | grep Class`).
5. Since I never specify the path to the correct library that it is looking for, `ld.so` by default looked at `/etc/ld.conf.cache` (which builds on `/etc/ld.conf.d/') to decide which directories to look in.  This is why it found the 4.7.2 version of quadmath.
6. To get the correct library at runtime, I need to set `export
   LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/gcc/5.5.0/lib64`.

**Summary**, it was finding the correct library at compile time using `ld` (b/c it looked at the relative paths of gcc) but could not find the correct library at run time (b/c LD_LIBRARY_PATH was incorrectly set).  The solution is : 
`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/gcc/5.5.0/lib64`. `-rpath` is not a valid option when building a shared library.

Answer (score 1):

The path specified by --rpath option will be hard coded into binary you created. At running time, `ld` will search dependent libraries from those paths preferentially. This is determined by [ld.so](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html).

But when you compile program, The linker will search dependent libraries from  LD_LIBRARY_PATH and those folder you specified by -L option. At compiling time, the path specified by --rpath do not take effect. This is determined by [ld, the GNU linker](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/ld-2.9.1/html_mono/ld.html).