# How to create an executable that links to a static library using a Makefile?

Tags: c, makefile

I'm new to C, and Makefiles are giving me a hard time. Within the Makefile, I want to make an executable that links to a static library. My understanding is that to generate an executable from `test.c` located in `src/project` the command would be `gcc src/project/test.c -o test`, and this executable would be named test. If I wanted to have the executable also link with a static library, `lib.a` how would I do that?

Comment: Sounds like your real confusion is about compiling and linking in C, rather than makefiles... just sayin'.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, `lib.a` is not a canonically "valid" static library filename, library filenames should start with `lib` and continue with the actual name of the library, e.g. `libsomething.a`. You would then link such library with `-lsomething`, assuming it is in the appropriate system directories. If not, you can add `-Lpath/to/directory` to make the linker also look into `path/to/directory` for `libsomething.a`. See also: [Order in which library directories are searched and linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36015224/order-in-which-library-directories-are-searched-and-linked). Alternatively, in case of a static library you could also add the library directly to the GCC command line: `gcc prog.c libsomething.a`.

In a very basic `Makefile` I would do something like this:

```
test: src/project/test.c path/to/libsomething.a
    gcc $^ -o $@
```

Answer (score 1):

> If I wanted to have the executable also link with a static library, lib.a how would I do that?

Short answer is: just include the library in the `gcc` command using

```
        gcc src/project/test.c -o test libstuff.a
```

Or use

```
       gcc src/project/test.c -o test -lstuff -Llibfolder
```

`-L` adds the `libfolder` to the list of folders where search for libraries are done. There is a folder search sequence for libraries similar to what happens with `#include` processing.

#### back to make

I will show a minimal example of how to build and use an static library in C and manage its use via a very short makefile, under Linux Ubuntu 20.

This is minimal and just for demonstration purposes. There are better ways to write this but I hope that writing this way will make easier for you to follow the logic.

Note: `ar` is the archiver in `Linux`, just like `LIB` in `Windows`. The program that manages creation of libraries.

### Example

Take a folder with these 4 files

```
    Makefile  myLib.c  myLib.h  testing.c
```

We want to build a library `libmyLib.a` from `myLib.c` and use it in `testing`

#### The C sources

For the library:

```
// myLib.h
int twice(int);
```

```
// myLib.c
#include    <stdio.h>
int twice(int value) { return value + value; }
```

The test program

```
// testing.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "myLib.h"
int main(void)
{   int x = 42;
    printf("x = %d, twice(%d) = %d\n", x, x, twice(x)  );
    return 0;
}
```

#### test output

`testing` just calls `twice(42)` and outputs `84`

```
x = 42, twice(42) = 84
```

#### using the `makefile`

We want to type `make` and have `libmyLib.a` built, `testing.c` compiled and `testing` generated.

Something like (with `make` output suppressed by now):

```
so_user@DSK-2009:~/projects/so0802$ ls -ltr
total 32
-rw-r--r-- 1 so_user so_user   266 Aug  2 17:46 Makefile
-rw-r--r-- 1 so_user so_user    26 Aug  2 18:23 myLib.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 so_user so_user   155 Aug  2 18:23 testing.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 so_user so_user    79 Aug  2 18:23 myLib.c
so_user@DSK-2009:~/projects/so0802$ make

// supressed output //

so_user@DSK-2009:~/projects/so0802$ ls -ltr
total 44
-rw-r--r-- 1 so_user so_user   266 Aug  2 17:46 Makefile
-rw-r--r-- 1 so_user so_user    26 Aug  2 18:23 myLib.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 so_user so_user   155 Aug  2 18:23 testing.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 so_user so_user    79 Aug  2 18:23 myLib.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 so_user so_user  1792 Aug  2 18:42 testing.o
-rw-r--r-- 1 so_user so_user  1368 Aug  2 18:42 myLib.o
-rw-r--r-- 1 so_user so_user  1510 Aug  2 18:42 libmyLib.a
-rwxr-xr-x 1 so_user so_user 16760 Aug  2 18:42 testing
so_user@DSK-2009:~/projects/so0802$ ./testing
x = 42, twice(42) = 84
so_user@DSK-2009:~/projects/so0802$
```

`make` is an absurdly clever program that takes into account the last modification time of the files to, yes, *make* things up to date. `make` is based on so called makefiles, whose name defaults to Makefile. In the makefile things to be updated are called `targets`.

A `makefile`, even for a short project, can be a complex thing. But is always easier than not using one.

#### what would a `make` run do?

you can present the so called `targets` to `make`. If you just type `make` the program will search for a file named `Makefile` and inside the file for a target named `all`.

The first command below only updates the library, while the second will try the target `all`

```
    make libMylib.a
    make
```

#### `make -n`

You can always try `-n` and `make` will list what the program will do to update  the targets.

Following the example above...

```
so_user@DSK-2009:~/projects/so0802$ make -n
make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
so_user@DSK-2009:~/projects/so0802$
```

As the targets are all updated. Now suppose `testing.c` is changed:

```
so_user@DSK-2009:~/projects/so0802$ touch testing.c
so_user@DSK-2009:~/projects/so0802$ ls -ltr
total 44
-rw-r--r-- 1 so_user so_user   266 Aug  2 17:46 Makefile
-rw-r--r-- 1 so_user so_user    26 Aug  2 18:23 myLib.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 so_user so_user    79 Aug  2 18:23 myLib.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 so_user so_user  1792 Aug  2 18:42 testing.o
-rw-r--r-- 1 so_user so_user  1368 Aug  2 18:42 myLib.o
-rw-r--r-- 1 so_user so_user  1510 Aug  2 18:42 libmyLib.a
-rwxr-xr-x 1 so_user so_user 16760 Aug  2 18:42 testing
-rw-r--r-- 1 so_user so_user   155 Aug  2 18:57 testing.c
so_user@DSK-2009:~/projects/so0802$ make -n 
gcc -c -Wall testing.c
gcc -o testing testing.o libmyLib.a
so_user@DSK-2009:~/projects/so0802$
```

And you see that, as `testing.c` is newer, **but as the library has not changed**, we need to compile the program and link it with the library:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 toninho toninho   266 Aug  2 17:46 Makefile
-rw-r--r-- 1 toninho toninho    26 Aug  2 18:23 myLib.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 toninho toninho    79 Aug  2 18:23 myLib.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 toninho toninho  1368 Aug  2 18:42 myLib.o
-rw-r--r-- 1 toninho toninho  1510 Aug  2 18:42 libmyLib.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 toninho toninho   155 Aug  2 18:57 testing.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 toninho toninho  1792 Aug  2 19:00 testing.o
-rwxr-xr-x 1 toninho toninho 16760 Aug  2 19:00 testing
```

But now we change `myLib.c` and try `make -n`:

```
so_user@DSK-2009:~/projects/so0802$ touch myLib.c
so_user@DSK-2009:~/projects/so0802$ make -n
gcc -c -Wall testing.c
gcc -c -Wall myLib.c
ar rcs libmyLib.a myLib.o
gcc -o testing testing.o libmyLib.a
so_user@DSK-2009:~/projects/so0802$
```

since the library changed, the header file could have also changed so we need to compile `testing.c` also. And call `ar` to rebuild the library, before generating a new `testing` executable.

#### The makefile used here

```
all: testing

clean:  
    rm *.o
    rm *.a
    rm testing

testing: testing.o libmyLib.a
    gcc -o testing testing.o libmyLib.a

testing.o: testing.c myLib.c myLib.h
    gcc -c -Wall testing.c

myLib.o:    myLib.c myLib.h
    gcc -c -Wall myLib.c

libmyLib.a: myLib.o
    ar rcs libmyLib.a myLib.o
```

I hope it is a bit clear how things go with `make`. Fell free to ask back about this.

the things before `:` are the targets

- the `clean` target is usual, and you see here it just removes things
- the things listed after a target are called dependencies, and it makes sense: if any of the dependencies are newer than the target the commands below the line of dependencies are run.
- `make` is deeply recursive in the search of targets to update